# Losing reputation for unaccepted answers?

Tags: support, reputation

While browsing through another users reputation, I noticed an entry that sais "-15 unaccepted". Since I have answered a question and was not accepted in the end, I checked my own rep and found nothing of the sort.

According to the FAQ the only way to lose rep is by downvotes and even then only one or two points at the same time.

Now I am courious to know under which circumstances one can lose rep by unaccepted answers.

[Example, browse to Nov 15](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/7424/fezter?tab=reputation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to happen if a user's answer is first accepted (+15) but then the acceptance is removed again (-15 => total 0).

I think this makes sense since it can turn out that the answer is wrong after all or that there is a better solution which should be accepted.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: (+1) I suspect that one can also lose those points when the thread itself is merged with another one and, possibly, when the acceptor's account is destroyed.